# how to add ZERO on beginning of binary number

Tags: c++

```cpp
void to_binary(int x)
{

    while (x)
    {
        a4 = x % 2;
        x /= 2;
        new_b += a4 * pow(10, g);//g=0
        g++;
    }
}
```

I wrote the function of converting a number to a binary number system, but there is one but if the number has leading zero, for example, 0011, then I see only 11 in the console. Can I fix this problem? I thought through the `vector` and `bitset` but they don`t work for me also.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - including printing. Numbers do not store their leading zeros, that would be useless.

Comment: The binary numbers 0011 and 11 are exactly the same. The lack of a [mcve] also makes it difficult to answer your question. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Use std::string(number_of_leading_zeros_needed,'0'); when printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not elaborate what was wrong with `std::bitset`. For me it seem to do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    unsigned long long x = 3;

    // 8 digits
    std::cout << "x = " << std::bitset<8>(x) << std::endl;
    // 4 digits
    std::cout << "x = " << std::bitset<4>(x) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
x = 00000011
x = 0011
```